# Check if an GUI application is running (and responsive)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to check if an application (WinForms GUI application) is running or not. Currently I use this code:

```
bool isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("SomeApp.exe").Any();
```

This solution has one major problem: when the application crashes, e.g. due to a missing DLL, the usual  Windows error message "Application Bla stopped working..." pops up. And while this message box is shown, the process is still there and my code returns true.

Is there any other way to check if the application is actually *responsive* (e.g. by sending some message to the window and wait for a response)?

Comment: Have you checked the [Responding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.responding?view=netcore-3.1) property of the process?

Comment: That sounds EXACTLY like the solution I was looking for. Thanks! Would you mind making it an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. :D  I've posted it as an answer. Should I delete my comments to make this discussion more focused?

Answer (score 0):

The Process class exposes a property called `Responding` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.responding?view=netcore-3.1)). It tries to contact to the UI and if it is not responding immediately then it will return with `false` indicating that the UI is currently not responsive.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. Although it looked good in theory, it does not work. My test application crashes on startup (I deleted its .exe.config file so that no dependencies are found), and the Windows error message pops up. Still "Responding" returns true (although the GUI is clearly not responsive).

Comment: @Boris Does your process has a `MainWindowHandle`? Because it is [checking against that](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,4a6008b8d55b354b), and it there isn't any then it will return true.

Comment: Yes. Its a very simple WinForms application. The main form is created and visible. After that the crash occurs and the modal Windows error message pops up (locking/blocking the main form of the application).

Comment: @Boris Can you call please the `MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()` on the process to be sure it is different than zero?

Comment: The handle is 1115042, which seems to be a reasonable value.

Comment: @Boris Are both application running on x86 or x64 build? BTW are we talking about .NET Framework or .NET core? Because of Winforms, I suppose the operating system is Windows.

Comment: The GUI application is written in good old .NET Framework 4.7 and compiled for x86. The checking tool is a Powershell script (I don't know which .NET it is using behind the scenes or if it is executed as x86 or x64).

Comment: @Boris I'm out of idea, sorry.